# Adafruit Airlift ESP32-WROOM-32E: FW update destroyed the WiFi module

Tags: microcontroller, esp32

I updated the Adafruit Airlift ESP32-WROOM-32E to "NINA_W102-1.7.4", but that caused it to stop working completely. I finally used an FTDI module to erase it and then re-install a previous version (NINA_W102-1.7.3), but no difference.

I checked the module with the Google Chrome ESP Tool, python.exe esptool and flash_download_tool_3.9.2. They show the upload was successful, however, no Arduino sketch works, as if the ESP32 module is dead.

```
\Python\Python39\site-packages> python.exe esptool --chip esp32 --port COM4 --baud 115200 run
esptool.py v4.1
Serial port COM4
Connecting...
Chip is ESP32-D0WD-V3 (revision 3)
Features: WiFi, BT, Dual Core, 240MHz, VRef calibration in efuse, Coding Scheme None
Crystal is 40MHz
MAC: e8:9f:6d:d3:0f:74
Stub is already running. No upload is necessary.
Hard resetting via RTS pin...
```

Comment: `I updated the Adafruit Airlift ESP32-WROOM-32E to "NINA_W102-1.7.4", but that caused it to stop working` ... maybe that is not true

Comment: what should the esptool command and output in the Question demonstrate?